# Unexpected system shutdown after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

After I upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7, my laptop would unexpectedly shutdown from time to time. From the event viewer, I can see the following two error messages:

> Windows failed to resume from hibernate with error status 0xC000007B.
>
> The previous system shutdown at 3:59:34 PM on ‎3/‎16/‎2016 was
>   unexpected.

I have no idea what causes the error. A few Google searches all don't help.

I also make sure that I already have the latest graphic driver ( Intel HD graphic 3000). I did this by running the update device software in the device manager a few times:

[image]

And made sure that each time I got a "your device is the latest" message.

When I downgraded to Windows 7, everything was working fine. I have no idea what could have caused the error in Windows 10. What else could be the error?